# android on raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, android

I am planning to buy a rpi 3 for Android. It needs to use the built-in Bluetooth. I am wondering how stable the current Android ports are, especially for Bluetooth support? Which OS version is currently ported?

Comment: I heard you can run android on Pi 3 but officially its not really supported. It is people hacking the images and this causes it be slow or unstable. Please search for another board for Android.

Comment: *" I am planning to buy a rpi 3 for Android."* -> Personal opinion based on posts here by people who do use Android on the Pi: **Don't bother.**  This isn't to say it won't or can't work, but if what you want is an android device of this sort, you will almost certainly be much, much happier if you splurge the extra $20 on an Android TV box.  Also worth noting the ones in that price range (~$70-100 US, if we consider the additional cost of an SD card, power supply, and case for the Pi 3) generally have significantly better hardware specs than a Pi 3.

Comment: There are plenty of SBCs with Android support (AFAIK Orange Pis are even shipped with Android installed)

Answer (score 0):

After four years , Android for any Raspberry Pi model is still in **beta** state.
You can follow the progress of the community porting efforts [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-rpi).

After 2012 , the foundation took the stance that they see little benefit in supporting Android , [as they now percieve it as mainly encouraging consumption instead of creation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#softwareAndroid).